# Key to switch between vertex, edge and face in Maya bindings

Tags: shortcut

Is there a keyboard map to switch between vertex, edge and faces in Edit mode using the Maya key bindings?

I'm also on a laptop with Emulate Numpad set.

It's documented that "Ctrl-Tab" should work with Blender keybindings but this switchers to Weight Paint Mode instead. (So I can't use that to search the key bindings to find/switch to something useful.)

In Maya, the keys are F9, F10 and F11, but these do something else, regardless of what key bindings are selected.

(If someone knows a good way to *find* Maya bindings in Blender that would be good too)

In Blender 2.78a.

Comment: I find the default element-switching  in edit mode painful - this isn't the Maya binding, (and it's not perfect either), but I use [1234Select](https://github.com/Pullusb/SB_1234Select). Things will change in 2.8, by all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is documented for default Blender layout; there it changes selection mode in Edit mode, in Object mode it activates Weight Paint.
In Maya bindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches to Weight Paint interaction mode both in Object and Edit modes.
It appears that select mode menu in this case will be on clicking <kbd>RMB</kbd>.

I suggest refering to User Preferences > Input window to check for the key bindings there.